# Search for long string (>50 characters) and record match

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

I have a piece of code that looks for a string and then records if that matches. The code works fine when the string is not longer than 50 characters. However above this, say for a string of 100 or 150 characters it bases a match only on the first 50 characters in the string rather than the full 100/150 character string.

Is there a way to make sure it counts matches based on the full string length? Im using an `awk` program as currently a score is based on birthdate and being less than a column and then the long string matching.

```bash
want2=$( awk '{print $4}' temp10_0.txt | head -1 )
dob_want2=$(head -1 year.txt )
awk -v a="$want2" -v b="$dob_want2" '{ if ($1==a && $2<=b) print $0, "1";else print $0, "0"}' temp25_0.txt>  temp11_0.txt
```

- Input data in `temp25_0.txt` is as follows

  ```
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 2016 
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 2008  
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 2013
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 2000
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 1987
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 1965
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555150000555555515515551011155111555115155101155511 2000
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555000551511115555555155155511111551115551151551111555 2007
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111150500 2016
  ```
- `want2` is

  ```
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511
  ```
- `dob_want2` is

  ```
  2019
  ```
- Desired output is

  ```
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 2016 1
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 2008 1  
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 2013 1
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 2000 1
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 1987 1
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111155511 1965 1
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555150000555555515515551011155111555115155101155511 2000 0
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555000551511115555555155155511111551115551151551111555 2007 0
  51511151511115551515555551111111555115511511111511115151111555151555511115511551511555551555155555555151111555555515515551111155111555115155111150500 2016 0
  ```

(I know it would be easier to read if the lines were shorter, but the line length seems to be the whole issue here.)
Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: My guess is that awk interprets the long strings of digits as numbers, and that you lose precision, resulting in incorrect comparisons.

Comment: @dhag ah, good point. The OP should force a string comparison with `$1==(a"")`.

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. Perhaps explain why all lines from the input appear to be selected, even though `want2` is only one value?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @dhag You need to scroll the text quoted windows completely to the right to see the difference. The aim is to append a `1` or `0` rather than actually filter the output.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton  the edit of $1==(a"") works! Really appreciate that!!

Comment: @AdminBee: Yes, I had read the whole lines, and I still could not understand the significance of `want2`, since it does not appear to filter the lines or do anything to them, plus the value for the column inserted does not seem to match the description in the question.

Comment: @dhag it adds 1 to the end of the lines where $1 is the same string as want2 and $2 is less than or equal to the numeric value of dob_want2, and adds 0 to the end otherwise. Scroll all the way right on the expected output to see those 0s and 1s.

Comment: @EdMorton: Indeed it does! I had misunderstood the snippet. The question should include your explanatory comment. (I had read the whole lines and noticed the inserted zeroes and ones, I had simply misunderstood how they were supposed to be computed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input (e.g. `$1`) that looks like a number is of type (roughly) `numeric string` (aka `strnum`) and so will be treated as a string or a number depending on the context in which it's first used. The variable `a` is also a `numeric string` and  the first place both are used is in the comparison `$1==a`. Per the comparison type table at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Typing-and-Comparison a strnum vs strnum comparison is treated as numeric but you need it to be treated as string to avoid loss of precision for large numbers and so you need to concatenate a null string to either side of the comparison to make it a strnum vs string comparison which is a string comparison.

```
awk -v a="$want2" -v b="$dob_want2" '{ print $0, ($1==(a"") && $2<=b) }'
```